# To find maximum occurance names in a list of tuple in PIG

Tags: max, apache-pig, find-occurrences

I have a file as:

```
1,Mary,5
1,Tom,5
2,Bill,5
2,Sue,4
2,Theo,5
3,Mary,5
3,Cindy,5
4,Andrew,4
4,Katie,4
4,Scott,5
5,Jeff,3
5,Sara,4
5,Ryan,5
6,Bob,5
6,Autumn,4
7,Betty,5
7,Janet,5
7,Scott,5
8,Andrew,4
8,Katie,4
8,Scott,5
9,Mary,5
9,Tom,5
10,Bill,5
10,Sue,4
10,Theo,5
11,Mary,5
11,Cindy,5
12,Andrew,4
12,Katie,4
12,Scott,5
13,Jeff,3
13,Sara,4
13,Ryan,5
14,Bob,5
14,Autumn,4
15,Betty,5
15,Janet,5
15,Scott,5
16,Andrew,4
16,Katie,4
16,Scott,5
```

I want the answer with names most appeared i.e max
(Scott,6)

Comment: So how would you go about trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some ambiguity in your question.

What exactly do you want.

Do you want a list of user count in descending order?

OR

Do you want just (scott,6) i.e. only one user with maximum count?

I have successfully solved both the things,on the sample data which you gave.

If the question is of first type then,

```
a = load '/file.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,number:int);
g = group a by name;
g1 = foreach g{ 
      generate group as g , COUNT(a) as cnt;
}; 
toptemp  = group g1 all; 
final = foreach toptemp{
        sorted = order g1 by cnt desc;
        GENERATE flatten(sorted);
};
```

This will give you a list of users in descending order as,

```
(Scott,6)
(Katie,4)
(Andrew,4)
(Mary,4)
(Bob,2)
(Sue,2)
(Tom,2)
(Bill,2)
(Jeff,2)
(Ryan,2)
(Sara,2)
(Theo,2)
(Betty,2)
(Cindy,2)
(Janet,2)
(Autumn,2)
```

If the question is of second type then,

```
a = load '/file.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,number:int);
g = group a by name;
g1 = foreach g{ 
      generate group as g , COUNT(a) as cnt;
}; 
toptemp  = group g1 all; 
final = foreach toptemp{
        sorted = order g1 by cnt desc;
        top = limit sorted 1;     
        GENERATE flatten(top);
};
```

This gives us only one result ,

```
(Scott,6)
```

Thanks.I Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ashu,i wanted to show only (scott,6) but i wanted to show using a MAX function. can u plz help here to get the result by the same

Comment: I don't think MAX can help us here.Why don't you try the second solution.Did you test the second solution?It works successfully.Can you tell me how can this be achieved using MAX?